# Why is the state of one UICollectionViewCell affecting another?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app written in swift in which i have cells that display products. I have a button to add the item to cart. When a product is out of stock, in the UICollectionViewCell's subclass, I use this code to disable the 'Add to Cart' button.

```
class Product: UICollectionViewCell {
    //Some code here
    //And here

    if(data.stock < 0){
      addToCartButton.isHidden = true;
    }

 }
```

When i scroll through the page, the Add to Cart button in other cells also get hidden, even if they don't satisfy the condition `data.stock < 0`. What is happening and how do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed is else condition buddy :)

```
    if(data.stock < 0){
        addToCartButton.isHidden = true;
    }
    else {
        addToCartButton.isHidden = false;
    }
```

**OR**

In collectionView cells gets reused when you scroll. You should make use of `prepareForReuse` to reset the state of UIComponents before they get reused.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    //reset all the fields of cell
    addToCartButton.isHidden = false
}
```

Using `prepareForReuse` is just a best practice and will solve your problem. But the real cause of the issue was missing else condition

Comment: Awesome. 
But how is it that the other properties of the cell (product name, price, etc.) work fine without the need to reset them in prepareForReuse?

Comment: @entropy-maximum : In case of other properties you would set them to one or the other value when cell gets reused. But because you had condition only to hide button and never to unhide it when cell gets reused you never brought it back adding else condition did the trick or else resetting it to its default value in prepareForReuse did the trick :)

Comment: @entropy-maximum : Consider accepting the answer if it helped

Comment: Thank you Sandeep, it's all clear now. Marked as correct!

Comment: @entropy-maximum : Thank you. Happy coding